# How do you use REGEXREPLACE in google sheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I'm importing some stuff from a google form into a google sheet. I want to delete the 'time' part of the timestamp, and copy it to another spreadsheet. I'm trying to use REGEXREPLACE to do this, but REGEXREPLACE is throwing a Formula parse error.  It seems like REGEX is a different programming language altogether, so am I not using REGEXREPLACE correctly? Or am I not putting the arguments in correctly? (Btw, I'm using the more general expression so that I can use it for any "entries")

Here's the actual doc:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YcHk5ylw3w7-V2AusaY2ktsyDEbtKzlIkFdS9quM8rE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Although I'm not sure that this is what you want, how about ``=TEXT('Form Responses 1'!A2,"m/dd/yyyy")`` instead of ``=REGEXREPLACE(('Form Responses 1'!A2), ' [0-9]+\:[0-9]+\:[0-9]+', '')``, because ``'Form Responses 1'!A2`` is used as date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace **single quotes** ('') with **double quotes** ("").

[image]

Comment: To work, You'd also need `TO_TEXT(A1)` as OP's dates are aligned right, while yours is aligned left,i.e., This won't work with `7/7/2018 20:35:57`

Answer (score 1):

To extract the date, you can use the `INT`-function

```
= INT(A2)
```

Then, formatted as Date, the time component is gone.

[image]

This works because the value of 1 represents 1 day of a DateTime. Time is a fraction of a day, for example, 0.33333 is 8 hours (1/3 of a day). The `INT`-function removes the decimal part and therefore only the date without time remains.